# Get most common column for each column value

Tags: python, pandas, split-apply-combine

I want the most common letter for each number. I've tried a variety of things; not sure what's the right way.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series

original = DataFrame({
    'letter': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'B'}, 
    'number': {0: '01', 1: '01', 2: '02', 3: '02', 4: '02'}
})

expected = DataFrame({'most_common_letter': {'01': 'A', '02': 'B'}})
```

Ideally I'm looking to maximize readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [DataFrame.mode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html) method:

```
In [43]: df.groupby('number')[['letter']] \
           .apply(lambda x: x.mode()) \
           .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
Out[43]:
       letter
number
01          A
02          B
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) + [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) + select first `index` values, because values are sorted.

Last convert `Series` [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and remove index name by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = original.groupby('number')['letter'] \
             .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])
             .to_frame('most_common_letter')
             .rename_axis(None)
print (df)
   most_common_letter
01                  A
02                  B
```

Similar solution:

```
from collections import Counter

df = original.groupby('number')['letter'] \
             .apply(lambda x: Counter(x).most_common(1)[0][0]) \
             .to_frame('most_common_letter') \
             .rename_axis(None)
print (df)
   most_common_letter
01                  A
02                  B
```

Or use [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mode.html):

```
df = original.groupby('number')['letter'] \
             .apply(lambda x: x.mode()[0][0])
             .to_frame('most_common_letter')
             .rename_axis(None)
print (df)
   most_common_letter
01                  A
02                  B
```

Comment: Is there a way to increase readability by using `.idxmax()` or something?

Comment: Unfortunately now I have no idea :(

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
    'letter': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'B'}, 
    'number': {0: '01', 1: '01', 2: '02', 3: '02', 4: '02'}})
>>> df['most_common_letter']=df.groupby('number')['letter'].transform(max) 
>>> df = df.iloc[:,1:].drop_duplicates().set_index('number')
>>> df.index.name = None
>>> df
   most_common_letter
01                  A
02                  B
```

Or this way if it helps readability:

```
>>> df['most_common_letter']=df.groupby('number')['letter'].transform(max) 
>>> df = df.drop('letter', axis=1).drop_duplicates().rename({'number': None}).set_index('number')
>>> df
   most_common_letter
01                  A
02                  B
```